# reveal browser regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code implimented in my system:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
#print_r($browser);

foreach ($browser AS $B => $V)
{
echo $B.":". $V."<br>";
}
```

Which returns the following:

```
browser_name_regex:�^.*$�
browser_name_pattern:*
browser:Default Browser
version:0
majorver:0
minorver:0
platform:unknown
alpha:
beta:
win16:
win32:
win64:
frames:1
iframes:
tables:1
cookies:
backgroundsounds:
cdf:
vbscript:
javaapplets:
javascript:
activexcontrols:
isbanned:
ismobiledevice:
issyndicationreader:
crawler:
cssversion:0
supportscss:
aol:
aolversion:0
```

how do I reveal the `browser_name_regex`?   and I do not think this is revealing the correct infroamtion.. because the `browser` i'm viewing this on is not my *Default Browser*
and i'm pretty sure i'm not using version 0 of chrome.

Comment: Have you correctly  read the manual of `get_browser()`? it requires a file called: `browscap.ini` on your server configuration.

Comment: Docs link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/function.get-browser.php) work correctly you have to download the latest [**browsercap.ini** file](http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/stream.php?Full_PHP_BrowscapINI) and **update your local browsercap.ini** file which is located at `echo ini_get('browscap');` or check the PHPinfo page.